# Is it safe to pass commands in startup applications

Tags: startup

I have a file which is created while running a certain task. I want to remove this file (if exist) on every fresh reboot. Can I use **Startup applictions** in ubuntu to remove this file.

example like this

```
rm -f $HOME/filename
```

Is this the right(without crashing my computer) way to remove a file on startup

Comment: I see no reason why it could be unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you are absolutely sure the filename/path is correct, I don't see why you shouldn't do it.

***however***

Startup Applications creates a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`. You cannot use relative or variable paths like `$HOME` in a `.desktop` file, the command simply won't run. You need to use absolute paths.

Comment: Jacob, you might want to rephrase `You cannot use relative paths like $HOME` part..Variable `$HOME` always expands to full path to user's home dir....you might say any variable or relative path won't work..

Comment: @heemayl isn't *You cannot use relative paths like $HOME* the same as *any variable or relative path won't work*?

Comment: I don't think so..my concern is `relative paths like $HOME` part..

Comment: @heemayl I am happy to edit if I understand what you mean, but what is the difference between *"You cannot use"* and *"won't work"*?

Comment: `$HOME` is not a relative path. That's the difference.

Comment: @muru, Ah, of course, will edit.